# Creating Span Like Google

Tags: javascript, css

[image]

How Can i recreate similar span (marked with red outline) by simple css & Html.Without using some library like bootstrap.Can anyone give me a fiddle demo on it?

Comment: No, that isn't what this site is for. You're expected to attempt to solve the problem yourself, and post your attempted solution.

Comment: Come on. Google "CSS nice buttons" and start reading.

Comment: Right Click -> Inspect element... ?

Comment: @meagar yes i am trying to figure it out.As Sverri M. Olsen said i am reading different option for creating such style.May be naive but created one in fiddle.I'm working on it to improve it a bit more.Fiddle Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/SageGandhi/Tsany/1/

Comment: If you inspect the button in the dev tools, you can literally see every detail of how it was constructed. What do you hope to learn from answers here that isn't already visible to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you make one :

HTML

```
<span class="btn">StackOverflow</span>
```

CSS

```
.btn{
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  background:#eee;
  padding:5px
}
```

Feel free to customize it :-)

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/YfQk6/1/

Enjoy the customization!

Some pro tip : 
Use Web Inspector Tool (F12) and see how the web elements are made..

Here is the definitive guide for you : https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: thanx rahul for giving me some direction.